# Open graph fitness.runs returning no data

Tags: facebook-opengraph, nike

I have a bunch of Nike+ run data which i'm assuming (based on the below article) is published to the open graph. It certainly looks that way in my timeline.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/29/early-success-stories--fitness-and-open-graph/

Frustratingly while my music.listens request works fine and returns all of my Spotify listens, my request for fitness.runs returns no data. Is this simply because Nike haven't integrated correctly with the Open Graph. Or perhaps I need to request extended permissions in my Auth token?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.runs

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all actions you need the correct permissions, in this case

`user_actions.fitness`

So the data returned from /me/fitness.runs for Nike will look like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10101118696330517", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Philippe Harewood", 
        "id": "13608786"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2013-03-22T23:15:56+0000", 
      "end_time": "2013-03-22T23:26:36+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2013-03-24T15:50:00+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Nike", 
        "namespace": "nikeapp", 
        "id": "84697719333"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "course": {
          "id": "476811255725972", 
          "url": "http://nikeplus.nike.com/plus/activity/running/detail/2118587303?external_share_id=CE32E1C4-93D8-48A7-A08F-6D5B4C13EE6A&is_new_meta=true", 
          "type": "fitness.course", 
          "title": "1.12 miles"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "fitness.runs", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "id": "10101118696155867", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Philippe Harewood", 
        "id": "13608786"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2013-03-19T22:03:32+0000", 
      "end_time": "2013-03-19T22:18:37+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2013-03-24T15:49:46+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Nike", 
        "namespace": "nikeapp", 
        "id": "84697719333"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "course": {
          "id": "502469216483599", 
          "url": "http://nikeplus.nike.com/plus/activity/running/detail/2118587302?external_share_id=EBF6BC1D-BDEA-4EE5-B18D-FBC576610F13&is_new_meta=true", 
          "type": "fitness.course", 
          "title": "1.49 miles"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "fitness.runs", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/13608786/fitness.runs?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=10101118696155867"
  }
}
```